# Possible way to have the WHERE before SET in UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute this query with no luck

```
UPDATE paliaused WHERE brand=34 SET brand='audi'
```

I know that the correct way of doing it (and did it succesfully) is:

```
UPDATE paliaused SET brand='audi' WHERE brand='34'
```

However I need to have the WHERE before SET because I am constructing the queries by replacing characters in a notepad file.

Also, are there any alternative ways of doing this?

Thank you

This is a part of my text

```
INSERT INTO models VALUES (978,'159');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (862,'156 S/W');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (979,'FIESTA');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (863,'156');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (980,'TERIOS');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (864,'A6');
```

where I need to transform to

```
UPDATE paliaused SET models='159' WHERE models='978'
```

Comment: You can't have `WHERE` before `SET`. We can provide you the alternate way when you post your way or tried code.

Comment: Show your notepad text that you need to transform, if you are using notepad++ it would be easy to construct this properly using regex find/replace.

Comment: You could write your own procedure `myUpdate(oldbrand,newbrand)` which will do `UPDATE paliaused SET brand = newbrand WHERE brand=oldbrand`. I do not know if this is applicable to your case though.

Comment: maybe you could build those queries with a script that would take the data out of a database table (I presume you need this to import brand names where you only have id's ?)

Comment: You'd think that MySQL could handle any order of phrases, but evidently it can't. So, what are you starting with (this "notepad file"), what kind of information are you updating, and how are you doing all this? There's probably a better way than what you're doing.

Comment: @smerny I have updated my question with examples. I do all the conversions with notepad++. Thank you.

Comment: So _HOW_ are you doing this? Are you reading each line of text with PHP, converting it to your UPDATE query, and feeding it to MySQL? It is trivial to extract the two fields using preg_match() and use them to build a query. By the way, there's no such thing as a "notepad file", and we don't care what editor you're using. It's a plain text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work in notepad++ regex find/replace (make sure regular expression is selected in the find dialog):

Find: `INSERT INTO models VALUES \(([^,]+),([^)]+)\);`
Replace with: `UPDATE paliaused SET models=$2 WHERE models='$1'`

With:

```
INSERT INTO models VALUES (978,'159');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (862,'156 S/W');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (979,'FIESTA');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (863,'156');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (980,'TERIOS');
INSERT INTO models VALUES (864,'A6');
```

Result will be:

```
UPDATE paliaused SET models='159' WHERE models='978'
UPDATE paliaused SET models='156 S/W' WHERE models='862'
UPDATE paliaused SET models='FIESTA' WHERE models='979'
UPDATE paliaused SET models='156' WHERE models='863'
UPDATE paliaused SET models='TERIOS' WHERE models='980'
UPDATE paliaused SET models='A6' WHERE models='864'
```

What is happening?

Parenthesis within the regex make up capture groups. The "capture groups" from above can then be used within the "Replace with" field in Notepad++ by using a $ followed by the index of that group.

Comment: You are just perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: No, this is not possible keeping inside SQL

Answer (score 0):

yes of-course,

```
$cond = 'WHERE brand=34';
"UPDATE paliaused SET brand='audi'".$cond;
```